# AsyncTask run 5 times and then not run doInBackground method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

click the button to call this method:

```
private void goRegister(final boolean isUsername) {
    new Loading.LoadTast(ctx) {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Looper.prepare();
            String msg=doRegister(isUsername);
            closeProgressDialog();
            if(msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
                SmartNgApplication.getInstance().exit();
            } else {
                BaseHelper.showToast(ctx, msg);
            }
            Looper.loop();
            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

and this is LoadTast class:

```
public abstract static class LoadTast extends AsyncTask &lt;Integer, Integer, String &gt; {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private Context ctx;

    public LoadTast(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    protected abstract String doInBackground(Integer... params);

    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "", "loading...", true, false);
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        BaseHelper.showToast(ctx, result);
    }

    public void closeProgressDialog() {
        if(progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

my program is:
when I click 5 times the button don't call `doInbackground` method and the screen always run a loading. I guess the code is run `onPreExecute` and not run `doInbackground`. Why??
in the `AsyncTask` has a thread pool,the `CORE_POOL_SIZE=5`. How to solution the program,Help me thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asyncTask isn't supposed to run its doInBackground more than once , and it's also not supposed to be a loopy thread .

asyncTask is supposed to be a one time thing that you run , and you can only assume that if multiple asyncTasks have executed , at least one will run at the same time.

another thing i've noticed : you called `closeProgressDialog` from within `doInBackground` , but that's a UI related operation  ,while the `doInBackground` is being ran on a non-UI thread.

Comment: i remove closeProgressDialog in doInBackground  the code is run well

Comment: i don't understand . did it fix your problem? if so, please tick this answer . if not , please tell us what is the status. as i've written , asyncTask isn't supposed to be executed more than once. if you wish to execute the same task more than once , you must create multiple instances of the task .

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem myself. I solved it by executing the `AsyncTasks` in the `thread pool`, instead of `serial`.

To do this, you have to call your AsyncTasks like this:

```
YourAsyncTask task = new YourAsyncTask();
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

That should solve the issue you have.